# Data structure for set inclusion queries

Tags: database, algorithm, search

**What I've done so far**: I have a map of sets (sort of database), where each set is a collection of strings (different features measured by a doctor). It looks like this:

```
{{"temperature", "blood pressure"}: Model1, {"temperature", "weight"}: Model2, {"temperature", "blood pressure", "weight"}: Model3}
```

Each set maps to a ML model that is used for that particular measurements. Sets may have different number of features, overlapping features (e. g. "temperature" is frequent).

**Task**: doctor makes some measurements, e. g. someone measured only `{"temperature", "weight"}`. I have to check which sets from my database are **inclusive** in this set, so I know which model can be used with this data, e. g. for this example there is Model2 available. It's okay if the model does not require all measured features - I only require that the model does not need more features than those measured. I need a data structure to effectively make such queries.

**Data**: it's not organized in any way yet, I'm also not bound to a particular language (I prefer Python, since the rest of application is in it, but it's not required). I can modify it in any way that' required, e. g. identify a model by a string ID, or throw this into some relational/non-relational database.

**Question**: what data structure / database type / data organization will be effective for such queries? I'm open to implementing data structures myself, as well as using SQL, MongoDB or any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure that you want is a trie.  That is, order the features in a canonical order (alphabetical works, frequency of feature in your models is somewhat more efficient) and put them into a nested structure `(models, further_lookups)` like this:

```
([], {
    'blood pressure': ([], {
        'temperature': ([Model1], {
            'weight': ([Model3], {})
        }),
    }),
    'temperature': ([], {
        'weight': ([Model2], {})
    }),
})
```

And now given a particular set of fields, you navigate in along the path you have and collect all of the models you run across.  Which is to say `[]` for the start, `[]` after `'temperature'` and `[Model2]` after `'weight'`.

Note that you have to try both using and not using any particular field.  So if you had `'blood pressure'` as well then you'd need to both try searching for models with `'blood pressure'` and without.  This is easily done with recursion.  It theoretically can take exponential time in the number of features that you have, but is unlikely to do so in practice.

I don't have recommendations for a good implementation of a trie in a data store.

Comment: I was also initially thinking about trie, but I'm worried about the exponentiality. It's not that uncommon to have a few measurements, sure, but also about 30. Do you know any way to speed up such search? Space requirements are not really a problem.

Comment: @qalis The branching is limited by how many models you have.  Also, heuristically, ordering the features from most commonly used to least commonly used, will allow you to quickly whittle away large blocks of models that will reduce the odds of exponential branching.  But no matter what you do, if you have every feature then you will return every model.

Comment: That said, you can also return a generator that will search for the models.  That way you may take exponential time to finish, but will start returning results ASAP.